# Apache Spark - capturing Kafka data on streaming event to trigger workflow

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

In a nutshell, I'm a developer attempting to use Spark to move data from one system to another. Raw data in one system to crunched, summarized form, into a homegrown analytics system.

I'm very new to Spark - my knowledge limited to what I've been able to dig up and experiment with over the last week or two.

What I'm picturing is; using Spark to watch for an event from Kafka as a trigger. Capture that entity/data on the consumer event and use it to tell me what needs to be updated in the analytics system. I would then run the relevant Spark queries against the raw Cassandra data and write the result to a different table on the analytics side, which the dashboard metrics call as a data source.

I have a simple Kafka structured streaming query working. While I can see the object consumed being outputted to the console, I'm unable to retrieve the Kafka record when the consumer event happens:

```
try {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master(this.sparkMasterAddress)
        .appName("StreamingTest2")
        .getOrCreate();

    //THIS -> None of these events seem to give me the data consumed?
    //...thinking I'd trigger the Cassandra write from here?
    spark.streams().addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryStarted(QueryStartedEvent queryStarted) {
            System.out.println("Query started: " + queryStarted.id());
        }
        @Override
        public void onQueryTerminated(QueryTerminatedEvent queryTerminated) {
            System.out.println("Query terminated: " + queryTerminated.id());
        }
        @Override
        public void onQueryProgress(QueryProgressEvent queryProgress) {
            System.out.println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress());
        }
    });

    Dataset<Row> reader = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "...etc...")
        .option("subscribe", "my_topic")
        .load();

    Dataset<String> lines = reader
        .selectExpr("cast(value as string)")
        .as(Encoders.STRING());

    StreamingQuery query = lines
        .writeStream()
        .format("console")
        .start();
    query.awaitTermination();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm also able to query Cassandra just fine w/ Spark SQL:

```
try {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("SparkSqlCassandraTest")
        .master("local[2]")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> reader = spark
        .read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("host", this.cassandraAddress)
        .option("port", this.cassandraPort)
        .option("keyspace", "my_keyspace")
        .option("table", "my_table")
        .load();

    reader.printSchema();
    reader.show();

    spark.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My thought is; trigger the latter w/ the former, get this thing bundled as a Spark app/package/whatever, and get it deployed into spark. At that point, I'd expect it to continually push updates to the metric table(s).

Will this be a workable, scalable, reasonable solution to what I need? Am I on the right path? Not opposed to using Scala if that's easier or better, in some way.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's a diagram of what I'm up against.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, assuming Spark isn't actualy transforming any data, then Kafka Connect is designed to read from a Kafka topic and write those events to downstream systems without writing any code yourself (a Cassandra connector already exists). That way, you don't need to figure out how to deploy and monitor a long-running Spark Streaming job outside your local machine

Comment: @cricket_007 I will need to perform transformations to crunch raw data from the data on the left, and keep a set of tables updated on the system on the right, which is the analytics layer that displays the outcomes/metrics from those transformations. I would simply like to use Kafka as a notification of what has changed in the raw data, in the origin system.

Comment: Got it... I'm not too familar with Spark to know if you can really access the low-level Kafka Consumer row-by-row event records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Learned about the ForeachWriter. Works great:

```
        StreamingQuery query = lines
            .writeStream()
            .format("foreach")
            .foreach(new ForeachWriter<String>() {
                @Override
                public void process(String value) {
                    System.out.println("process() value = " + value);
                }

                @Override
                public void close(Throwable errorOrNull) {}

                @Override
                public boolean open(long partitionId, long version) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .start();
```